# How to get null passwords over SSH working on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, password

I'm running the latest Raspbian image on a Model B. I attempted to create a null password by using `passwd -d`, blanking the password field for the user in `/etc/shadow`, and setting `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. This allows me password-less login over tty, but not ssh.

When I try to connect via SSH, I get the following in my `auth.log`:

```
sshd[8351]: Failed password for root from [my ip] port 49861 ssh2
```

I read that when OpenSSH is using PAM, you have to add "nullok" to the *auth* line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, so I amended mine as follows:

```
auth       required     pam_env.so nullok
auth       required     pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale nullok
```

But then I just get this in `auth.log`:

```
sshd[4418]: pam_env(sshd:setcred): unknown option: nullok
```

Now, I'm well aware of the security risks of this, but this Raspberry Pi is going to live on a local switch that will never be connected to a public network. I know I could set up private key login, but I'd rather not have to add each device's public key if I can avoid it. Is there any way to get null passwords working on this distro? I'm not too familiar with it, other than that it's Debian-based.

Edit to add: I also have `PermitRootLogin yes` set, and can login to this account when it has a non-blank password set, so it's not the fact that I'm trying to log into the root account. I tried making a different account, and I still get "failed password for ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `nullok` option can be used with the `pam_unix.so` and not the `pam_env.so`.

If pam_unix is installed in your Pi (most probably, it is), then this line will do the trick

```
auth       required     pam_unix.so nullok
```

EDIT:
I just found some time to play around.
I managed to make it work. Given that all the settings in sshd and pam.d are ok, you need to manually edit your `/etc/shadow` file and place this

`U6aMy0wojraho`

in the password field of all users you want to allow passwordless access. As you already know, passwords are hashed in the shadow file. The above string is the hash of *nothing* in raspbian's default hashing algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! That fixed the pam_env error, but it's still failing to login with a null pass: `raspberrypi sshd[19216]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=macbookpro.lan  user=root` and then `raspberrypi sshd[19216]: Failed password for root from 192.168.1.51 port 58094 ssh2`

Comment: I've edited my answer with a solution, tested and working. Being a security geek myself, I can only wish that you enjoy your intentional security hole! :)

Comment: Thanks! Clever, it works great. The only people that could SSH into this would be in the room and plugged in, so I'd have much bigger problems :P

Answer (score 1):

Answer specifically concerning the "empty password" part:

`passwd -d` will not set the password to an empty string, it will *delete* the password altogether, making it impossible for the user to log in using a password.

Setting an empty password (without manually editing `/etc/shadow`) can be done using

```
echo pi:`openssl passwd -salt xx ""` | sudo chpasswd -e
```

The first part of the command outputs the username, a `:` separator and an empty password hashed with a chosen salt value (here: `xx`). The second part sets the password for the user, `-e` meaning the password is already encrypted. Encrypting the password is necessary because `chpasswd` does not accept empty strings.